# Is there a way to get the n-th document from a mongoose collection by some arbitrary sorting criteria?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say we have a large collection of students, and each student's height is stored.

Is there a way to obtain the 50th (or N-th) tallest student, **without fetching all the students and locally sorting them by height**, using mongoose?

I would post my attempts, but this is such a simple query to explain that I feel it would just make the question unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`skip(n)`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip) to skip over the first `n` docs and use [`limit(m)`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) to limit the results from there to `m` number of docs.  Adding a [`sort`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) determines the order of the docs.

So in this case it would be:

```
Students.find().sort({height: -1}).skip(49).limit(1).exec(function(err, students) {
   ...
});
```